# Is there a way to replace a substring based on the number of occurrences?

Tags: java, regex

I want to remove every occurrence of `"*"` but ignore `"**"`, so for example, if I had `"testing *single star* and **double star**"`, the sentence after removing would be `"testing single star and **double star**"`.

I was thinking of using `replace("*", "")` but when I tried that, it got rid of all the stars.

What should I do?

Comment: Should we consider input with 3 stars? If so then how would you like to handle them?

Comment: @Pshemo 3 stars don't need to be considered but stribizhev's answer seems to work in all cases.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can leverage lookarounds

```
String s = "testing *single star* and **double star**".replaceAll("(?<![*])[*](?![*])", "");
```

See [IDEONE demo](http://ideone.com/VXtfKc) (result: `testing single star and **double star**`)

Putting `*` into a character class allows to match a literal asterisk without escaping.

The `(?<![*])` is a negative lookbehind checking if there is no asterisk before an asterisk, and `(?![*])` is a negative lookahead making sure there is no asterisk after the asterisk being matched.

Answer (score 3):

You could probably try with

```
yourString  = yourString.replaceAll("(\\*{2})|\\*","$1");
```

Explanation: `replaceAll` uses regular expression (regex) mechanisms. Also `*` is special character in regex so we need to escape it (I used `\\*` to do so, but you can also use `[*]` or surround it with `\\Q` `\\E`). Now lets see what this regex is:

- `(\\*{2})` - will try to match `**` and place it in group 1
- `|` - OR operator
- `\\*` - match only one `*`

So this solution will try to first find `**`, store it in group 1 and later replace it with match from group 1 (so we are replacing it with itself which means they will stay in text).
But if regex engine will not be able to find `**` and instead will will find `*`, group 1 will be empty since it can match only two stars (since that part of regex is surrounded with parenthesis). So our replacement `$1` will represent empty string which means we will remove single `*`.

So current solution will cause these changes:

```
*     ->       - found 1 star (remove it)
**    -> **    - found 2 stars (stay)
***   -> **    - found 2 stars (stay), 1 star (remove)
****  -> ****  - found 2 stars (stay), 2 stars (stay)
***** -> ****  - found 2 stars (stay), 2 stars (stay) and 1 star (remove)
```

---

If you don't want to affect 2 or more stars (like `***` should still be `***`) instead of `{2}` use `{2,}`, this will allow us to store in group 1 *two or more* stars (but not one).

Comment: I think you can describe this approach as "taking odd asterisk out" (thus, 1 turns into 0, 2 and 3 to 2, 4 and 5 to 4, etc.). Mine is a bit different since it only removes 1-asterisk sequences enclosed with non-asterisk symbols. Anyway, sportsmanship is what I am after :)

Comment: @stribizhev Yes, *odd* or with change described at end of my post *more than 2* :)